# Performance test done in client or servide?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, performance-testing

I have a website running in ASP.NET webforms. I planning to run performance tests using visual studio 2013 ultimate edition test tools. I have a very basic question.

Where is the performance test supposed to be run?

From a client machine or from server?

Could you please point me to good article on this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you want to measure.

To measure the uses experience then on a computer similarly located to those of the users of your website. To measure the raw performance of the website then on a computer located where network delays and bandwidth will not be an issue.

Another point to consider is how much monitoring of the servers you want to perform when running the test. Visual Studio load tests can collect performance counters from other computers during the test run. These might be the web servers, database servers, application servers, etc. Getting access to the the performance counters of these servers generally requires firewall and other permission changes. The counters also consume network bandwidth as they are transferred to the test computer(s). If these performance counters must be collected then that may require the test computer(s) to be within the company's filewalls.

If your test does collect performance counters from the various servers then one interesting test variation is a "do nothing" test that just collects the counters over a period of time during real use of the system. That provides a way of validating that the tests were representative of real use.